# multiple button determine which is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple buttons in a form (all are type 'submit'). I would like to determine which one of them is clicked. I am currently using:

```
$(".MyForm").click(function() {
    ...
}
```

to get values from my form. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your handler, 'this' is the DOM element that was clicked, and $(this) is the jQuery object for that DOM element. So...

```
$(".MyForm").click(function() {
  var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You define an id for each button then you can use $("#buttonid").click to define different action for each button you like or test the id with .attr('id')

Comment: The number of buttons for each form is not fixed - would this approach still work? The # of buttons are populated from database and could be different each time the page loads

Comment: @Aamir Mansoor: Yeah, I also thought about it. if that's the case then I guess the javascript also need to generate from the server side. If you have other idea, it'd be great to hear.